# SELECT all from 1 of 2 tables, based on the table with the most rows

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automationstudio

This is a bit of a weird question, but I will explain the problem first.

Every day we import a refreshed set of data in to a table called MARKETABLE_TABLE.

Sometimes there is an error with the generated data, and it has fewer records (say 400k instead of 800k).

Currently I am having to manually re-import the previous day's data when that happens, as having all the older data is better than having 60% of new data.

What I am trying to do:

I have a built 2 copies of the main data extension, MARKETABLE_TABLE_YESTERDAY and MARKETABLE_TABLE_TODAY.

After doing the import, I copy everything to the MARKETABLE_TABLE_YESTERDAY table.
The next day, a new import happens to the MARKETABLE_TABLE_TODAY table.

I then want to have a query run that looks at the rowcounts for these 2 tables.

If MARKETABLE_TABLE_YESTERDAY > MARKETABLE_TABLE_TODAY, copy everything from MARKETABLE_TABLE_YESTERDAY in to MARKETABLE_TABLE and continue with the automation.

If MARKETABLE_TABLE_YESTERDAY <= MARKETABLE_TABLE_TODAY, copy everything from MARKETABLE_TABLE_TODAY in to MARKETABLE_TABLE and continue with the automation.

Is it even possible to have 2 different SELECT statements within an IF statement comparing the size of the 2 tables, with the query itself always writing to a single final table?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation for this would be to instead use a SSJS script to determine if to retain the current TODAY table or to Import YESTERDAY again into the TODAY de. You would need a Script Activity, Validation Step, and a new DE.

You would utilize the AMPscript DataExtensionRowCount() function, but as Script Activities only allow SSJS, you will have to fudge it a bit to allow AMPscript in (unless you want to just put your AMPscript in a content block then call that block in via SSJS - either works.

```html
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var rcToday = Platform.Function.TreatAsContent('%'+'%=DataExtensionRowCount("MARKETABLE_TABLE_TODAY")=%' + '%')

var rcYesterday = Platform.Function.TreatAsContent('%'+'%=DataExtensionRowCount("MARKETABLE_TABLE_YESTERDAY")=%' + '%')

if (rcYesterday > rcToday) {
       var rows = Platform.Function.UpsertData("DE_CHECK",["ID"],["MARKETABLE_TABLE"],["ReRun"],["1"]);
} else {
        var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
        var action = "ClearData";
        var props = { CustomerKey: 'DE_CHECK' };
        var data = prox.performItem("DataExtension", props, action);
}
```

Then you put a validation step in the auto that looks at DE_CHECK and if it has a Rowcount > 1 then you continue, otherwise stop automation. Then have your final Step be a SQL Query to move YESTERDAY back into and overwrite TODAY.

Answer (score 0):

There may be better approaches, this one may help you.

1. Create 2 child automatons as below,

   - One with only one SQL activity to move data from MARKETABLE_TABLE_YESTERDAY in to MARKETABLE_TABLE
   - Second automation with only one SQL activity to move data from MARKETABLE_TABLE_TODAY to MARKETABLE_TABLE
2. Use the below in your Script activity to run Respective automation as per your above logic

```ampscript
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");
    var scr = "";
        scr += "\%\%[";
        scr += "If DataExtensionRowCount('MARKETABLE_TABLE_YESTERDAY') > 
DataExtensionRowCount('MARKETABLE_TABLE_TODAY') THEN";
        scr += "]\%\%";
    Write(TreatAsContent(scr));
</script>

<script  runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    //Change the MID to suit.
    prox.setClientId({ "ID": xxxxxxxx });

    // Need to retrieve the ObjectID for the Automation, which isn't available via the SFMC interface.
    var cols = ["Name", "ProgramID", "IsActive"];
    var filter = {
        Property: "Name",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: "xxx Name of your Automation to add MARKETABLE_TABLE_YESTERDAY xxx"
    };
    var desc = prox.retrieve("Automation", cols, filter);
    var props = { ObjectID: desc.Results[0].ObjectID};
    var action = "start";
    var opts = {};
    var res = prox.performItem("Automation", props, action, opts);
    var status = res.Status;
    var statusCode = res.Results[0].StatusCode;
    Write("status code: " + statusCode);
</script>

<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");
    var scr = "";
        scr += "\%\%[";
        scr += "ELSE";
        scr += "]\%\%";
    Write(TreatAsContent(scr));
</script>
<script  runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    //Change the MID to suit.
    prox.setClientId({ "ID": xxxxxxxx });

    // Need to retrieve the ObjectID for the Automation, which isn't available via the SFMC interface.
    var cols = ["Name", "ProgramID", "IsActive"];
    var filter = {
        Property: "Name",
        SimpleOperator: "equals",
        Value: "xxx Name of your Automation to add MARKETABLE_TABLE_TODAY xxx"
    };
    var desc = prox.retrieve("Automation", cols, filter);
    var props = {ObjectID: desc.Results[0].ObjectID};
    var action = "start";
    var opts = {};
    var res = prox.performItem("Automation", props, action, opts);
    var status = res.Status;
    var statusCode = res.Results[0].StatusCode;

    Write("status code: " + statusCode);
</script>       

<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("core", "1");
    var scr = "";
        scr += "\%\%[";
        scr += "ENDIF";
        scr += "]\%\%";
    Write(TreatAsContent(scr));
</script>
```

> > Thanks to @Greg for reminding that AMPscript cant be directly used in SSJS activity.
> > Also thanks to Ivan for this useful article https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/use-ampscript-to-enhance-ssjs-in-sfmc/

Comment: Cannot directly use AMPscript in a Script Activity. Would need to either store that in a Content Block and reference it in the activity or need to 'fudge' it with a TreatAsContent.

Comment: Thanks for reminding that AMPscript cannot be directly used in Script activity...... have updated my code

Comment: Thanks for this! I was hoping there would be a way to do it just in Automation Studio (as I don't have any SSJS experience), but guess I will need to log a ticket with the smarter people in my business :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this all in a single query without the overhead of a Script Activity.  Perhaps a query like this.

```sql
select
  both.id
, both.DE /* for debugging, remove this in final version */
, deCounts.todayCount /* for debugging, remove this in final version */
, deCounts.yesterdayCount /* for debugging, remove this in final version */
from (

  select 
  t.id
  , 'today' DE
  from MARKETABLE_TABLE_TODAY t

  union

  select 
  y.id
  , 'yesterday' DE
  from MARKETABLE_TABLE_YESTERDAY y

) both
outer apply (

  select 
    max(x.todayCount) todayCount
  , max(x.yesterdayCount) yesterdayCount
  from (

    select 
    count(*) todayCount
    , 0 yesterdayCount
    from MARKETABLE_TABLE_TODAY 

    union

    select 
    0 todayCount
    , count(*) yesterdayCount
    from MARKETABLE_TABLE_YESTERDAY 

  ) x

) DECounts
where 
  case
    when deCounts.todayCount >= deCounts.yesterdayCount then 'today' 
    else 'yesterday'
  end = both.DE
```

The `outer apply` combines the counts of both tables.  The outermost query combines rows from today and yesterday and tags them with `today` or `yesterday`.  The `case` statement in the `where` clause picks which set from the `both` result (based on the counts) to return.

I'd suggest experimenting with the query using this dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/w4Pl4rET